# Modify useState array of object

Tags: reactjs, use-state, arrayobject

I have a useState array of object as:

`const [processes, setProcesses] = useState([]);`

After fetching values from db it becomes:

```
[{processId: 0, status: "true"},
{processId: 1, status: "true"}]
```

Now I want to add new property to it so that it becomes like:

```
[{processId: 0, name:"process1",status: "true",active:"true"},
{processId: 1, name:"process2",status: "true",active:"true"}]
```

where the name is coming from:

```
var allProcNames=["process1","process2"]
```

I've tried the below:

```
var objProc = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(processes));

objProc.map((proc) => ({
        ...proc,
        name: procNames[proc.processId],
        active: true,
    }));
```

However it is logging the same only:

`[{processId: 0, status: "true"}]`

What can be done apart from adding a new column to db for the process name?

Comment: `.map` is not mutative. If you want the result of `map` you must assign it to a variable: `const mapped = objectProc.map(...)`.

Comment: let temp = objProc.map((proc) => {({
        ...proc,
        name: procNames[proc.processId],
        active: true,
    }));

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You shouldn't try to mutate the state directly.**
(Check *ref*: https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate)

You could use `filter` or `map` methods and update your current state with a whole new state:

```js
const [processes, setProcesses] = useState([
{processId: 0, status: "true"},
{processId: 1, status: "true"}
]);

const arrayObjUpdater = () => {
  const newArrayState = processes.map((currentProcess, idx) => ({
          ...currentProcess,
          name: `proccess${idx}`,
          active: "true"
  }));
  console.log(newArrayState); // See output below

  return setProcesses(newArrayState);
}

arrayObjUpdater();
// Output: [{processId: 0, name:"process1",status: "true",active:"true"}, {processId: 1, name:"process2",status: "true",active:"true"}]
```

Answer (score 2):

you can change the code like this.

```
    let temp = objProc.map((proc) => {
      return ({
        ...proc,
        name: procNames[proc.processId],
        active: true,
    }));

   setProcesses(temp);
```

In this case, you can store all process data on temp, and next set the value on state.
Don't forgot return. it's very necessary.